# Difference between the __lte and __gte in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out the difference between the __lte and __gte in Django.

The reason being that I am trying to create a function with dates that can work only with a time frame, so I've been researching between Field Lookups Comparison.

I've looked up several documentations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude

but didn't reach a conclusive answer.

Edited:

I learned that lte is **less than or equal** and gte **greater than or equal**

Here is some documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte)

Comment: from the names, I'd say they are "less than or equal" and "greater than or equal".

Comment: There is this strg+f thing in browsers (and any other program) that lets you search for things. A simple "gte" will do the trick (at the link that you provided). here have a look: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**`__lte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte) means that you constrain the field that is should be ***less than** or equal* to the given value, whereas the [**`__gte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte) means that the field is ***greater than** or equal* to the given value.

So for example:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field__gte=5)  # field ≥ 5
MyModel.objects.filter(field__lte=5)  # field ≤ 5
```

Answer (score 24):

according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

```
 __lte -> Less than or equal
 __gte -> Greater than or equal
 __lt -> Less than
 __gt -> Greater than


QuerySet(foo__lte=10) # foo <= 10
QuerySet(foo__gte=10) # foo >= 10
QuerySet(foo__lt=10) # foo < 10
QuerySet(foo__gt=10) # foo > 10
```

Answer (score 2):

gte stands for 'greater than or equal', lte stands for 'lower than or equal' accordingly